# How can I recreate the javascript alert box in HTML so it does not display "The page at blahblah says"

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a piece of code that displays an alert box when opened in your browser. See below. However, when opened, it says... The page at whateverwebsite.com says: - at the top.

How can I recreate it in HTML so it's exactly like the browsers default alert box?

Please help!

```
<script> function myFunction() { alert("Alert here"); } </script>
```

Comment: You need to use an existing library for having custom pop-up boxes.

Comment: An existing library? Please elaborate I'm quite new.

Comment: I need it exactly like it is with the default popup. But I need to customise where it says the website is from.

Comment: A JS library which has custom alert boxes like [BootboxJS](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Comment: Nothing can recreate the perfect alert box of the browser because it has some features which we can't replicate with Javascript. For example, a browser's alert boxes stops the code temporarily (prevent next line of code to be run)  until the user clicks on the OK.

Comment: Hmph. So you're telling me I can't do it? :(!

Comment: I am saying you can't perfectly replicate it but ofc you can using some libraries. Just that, they dont have the exact features as the native alert box.

Comment: Does anyone know of any legit looking Chrome popups/notifications I can use? I want it to be as much like the default as possible.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail exactly what you want to achieve. As others have said you cannot halt execution in the same way that the browser can so we need to know what effect you are aiming for. For example, do you want the whole of the rest of the page to not be accessible by the user when the popup is showing?

Comment: The pop up will be an on load pop up. I'm creating an error message and need it to not show the website it's coming from so need it coded.

Comment: Check out a few libraries that can create modal popups for you, like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/.